# Стать программистом гуманитарию за 2-3 года?

Tags: работа

Собственно вопрос для меня очень актуальный.
Как мне стать программистом?

В настоящий момент я работаю маркетологом (более 3 лет), однако с детства и до сих пор моим хобби был комп, поэтому пока не поздно хочу работать по призванию. Пробовал кодить, но по сути баловался.
В универ на очку уже поздно (26 лет), а заработок не хочу терять. Доход приличный, да и родственники не поймут))

С чего мне начать? Я планирую года за 2-3 постепенно превратить свое увлечение в дополнительный источник дохода, а там может и в основной.

Какая структура знаний должна быть? 
Что мне нужно знать? 
Какие языки учить и в какой последовательности?

Сферу деятельности я определил пока веб-разработку, т.к. данная категории легче на фрилансе (поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь).

Может у кого был подобный опыт....надеюсь на советы.

Вобщем подведу итог: 
Как мне с нуля стать программистом с актуальными навыками и знаниями?

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Для веб направления:

1) **Учите HTML**, смотрите примеры, сайты, исходные страницы сайтов. Достигните понимания в структуре html, т.е. можете сами от руки написать табличку, жирный текст, списки, заголовки, ссылки, якоря и т.д. Поймите что такое теги, атрибуты и т.д. и научиться правильно искать информацию по html (т.е. не обязательно знать все теги, можно просто уметь их находить)

> *Где писать*: блокнот, простые Web редакторы (с вводом только текста)
>
> *Источники информации*: различные учебники, в том числе и в интернете
>
> *время освоения*: если уделять по 1-2 часа в день, можно за 2 недели освоить

2) **Добавьте к HTMLу CSS**, это таблица стилей. Т.е. программирование еще не добавилось. Для начало надо будет понять что это за штука (css), и зачем она нужна. С помощью нее можно прописывать стили. Так же научитесь искать информацию.

> *Где писать*: блокнот, простые Web редакторы (с вводом только текста)
>
> *Источники информации*: различные учебники, в том числе и в интернете
>
> *время освоения*: если уделять по 1-2 часа в день, можно за 1 неделю освоить (если до этого вы поняли html)

3) **Добавьте к этому JavaScript**. Вот тут то и начинается программирования. На этом этапе посоветую изучить простые основы программирования: переменные, условия, циклы, функции. Пытайтесь писать простые вещи, и хорошо освоить основы, т.е. уверенно ими пользоваться. Поймите иерархию структуру HTML-а, и научитесь на чистом JS обращаться, получать и изменять элементы. Повторюсь, на чистом JS (не стоит лесть в JQuery на этом этапе)

> *Где писать*: блокнот, простые Web редакторы (с вводом только текста)
>
> *Источники информации*: различные учебники, в том числе и в интернете
>
> *время освоения*: если уделять по 1-2 часа в день, можно за 1-2 месяца освоить (но это индивидуально, как мозг человека примет логику)

4) **Перейдите к серверному языку** (я напишу про PHP). Поймите синтаксис у языка (циклы условия все принципы программирования будут схожи с JS, но синтаксис немного отличаться, ну и некоторые принципы). Поймите как генерится страница, что такое POST и GET запросы.

> *Где писать*: Web редакторы, NetBeans
>
> *Источники информации*: различные учебники, в том числе и в интернете, http://php.su
>
> *время освоения*: если уделять по 1-2 часа в день, можно за 2-4 месяца понять основы (но это индивидуально, как мозг человека примет логику)

5) **Углубите знания в JS (+JQuery) и PHP**, тут уже предлагаю сделать связь между JS и сервером. отправлять принимать POST и GET запросы. Время освоения 1 неделя.

6) **Освойте Базу Данных (SQL)** вообще понять что и как работает. как работать с таблицами, какие запросы и как лучше делать.

> *Где писать*: любая СУБД (Access, Oracle, ...)
>
> *время освоения*: если уделять по 1-2 часа в день, можно за 2 месяца понять основы

7) **Изучите связь БД и PHP** научитесь делать запросы из PHP, добавлять получать данные. Отображать таблицы и т.д. Для php советую работать с **mysqli**. Углубите свои полученные знания в пункте 6.

> *Где писать*: Web редакторы, NetBeans
>
> *Источники информации*: различные учебники, в том числе и в интернете, http://php.su
>
> *время освоения*: если уделять по 1-2 часа в день, можно за 2 месяца понять основы

8) **Углубитесь в знания программирования, ООП**, освойте знания классов, как в JS так и в PHP (любой другой серверный язык). Практикуйтесь, создавайте свои классы и т.д. Дальше время не буду писать, т.к. все расплывчато.

9) **Углубиться в программирование**, вообще, вы должны знать много-много различных алгоритмов и теорий. До этого момента мы занимались детским садом, подготовка к школе, так сказать. На этом шаге предлагаю изучить различные алгоритмы (**сортировка** - хоть и есть стандартные средства но знать надо, **комбинаторика**, **графы**, **деревья** - часто бывают полезны для веб разработчиков и т.д.). Это я к чему, для повышения навыков программирования решайте Олимпиадные задачи, изучайте готовые алгоритмы. Изучите дополнительные возможности программирования: регулярные выражения и т.д. Изучите теории и поймите как лучше создавать структуры баз, какие базы и таблицы необходимо создавать. Изучите теории по оптимизациям и написанием нагруженных систем (кэширование и другое).

> *Где решать*: например тут http://codeforces.ru/

10) **Применения знаний**, пробуйте изучайте различные CMS конструктора: Ucoz, Joomla, Drupal, ModX, WordPress. Применяйте свои навыки на них. Напишите по одному сайту на каждом из них )

11) **Углубление, фреймворки**, изучите какой-либо фреймворк, например **Yii** для PHP. К этому моменту вы должны уметь уже правильно создавать структуры баз, свободно писать на JS и PHP. Так же можно попробовать подключаться к стороним API, например к Vk.

12) **Ну и напоследок для веб-мастера** почитать про СЕО, знать хотя-бы что это за рыба.

**13) САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ!** Везде, и тем более в Программировании **необходима Практика**!, надо постоянно пробовать, ничего страшного если что-то не получается, вы должны учиться на ошибках, как своих так и чужих. Что-то прочитали?, тут же пишите. Есть друзья, которые без конца читают книги по программированию, но, практики у них мало.. в итоге книги много им не дают (ну знает он что можно вот так сделать, а сделать не может, т.к. не умеет применять свои знания к делу). Это как изучение боевых искусств - мастер вам каждый день по 15 часов объясняет что и как делать, куда бить, куда уходить, а вы просто слушаете. Когда дело дойдет до боя, вы ничего не сможете применить. Поэтому: **НУЖНО ПРАКТИКОВАТЬСЯ**

p.s. Надеюсь помог )

Comment: JОбезательно допиши...мне интересно следующие этапы для Web.Удивлен ,очень удевлен рамками изучения....

Comment: @zloctb вы на счет каких рамок, в смысле нашли что-то полезное, или не согласны с подходом? :)

Comment: Прекрасный ответ же!

Comment: @IVsevolod, хороший ответ. Сам бы я добавил изучение работы сети отдельным пунктом до изучения серверной части. На том уровне, чтобы человек мог представить картину в целом - что куда ушло, почему, что вернулось и почему оно работает или нет :)

Comment: @xEdelweiss ну это понять можно за пару часов, а так да, человек должен понять отличия сервера и клиента, как идут запросы, где выполняется php (например), и что он возвращает.

Comment: @IVsevolod,даже не надеялся на столь шикарный и подробный ответ, сразу виден опыт и четкое осознание профессии. Большое спасибо.

Comment: >> 4) Перейдите к серверному языку (я напишу про PHP)

...

Comment: Все правильно написали. Практика и еще раз практика.

Answer (score 9):

Нда... 1-й ответ предполагает переформатирование гуманитария в несчастного веб кодера, правда, топикстартер желает им быть - так что ответ вроде в точку.

Добавлю свои 5 копеек в холивар:

Мозги гуманитария устроены немного по другому нежели мозги приверженца точных наук (к коим программирование как ни крути относится). Гуманитарий рассуждает обычно качественными категориями типа:

> творчество Некрасова пронизано
> болью к судьбе русскаго крестьянства,
> а Фет как потомственный помещик не
> понимает русскую общину и занимается больше
> самолюбованием и идеализированием
> русской деревни

В программировании все не так. Четкие конструкции `if-then-else`, `do-while` и проч. Я вообще сомневаюсь, что переформатирование гуманитария в прогеры возможно, хотя примеры конечно же есть.

У меня был друг гуманитарий, который стал прогером - так вот, в итоге он мне выдал, что программирование это как написание книги: нужно придумать сюжет (идея программы), рассадить персонажи (объекты, классы, модули, рутины), описать сюжет взаимодействием персонажей (правила общения классов, модулей) - в общем это схоже с придумыванием своего мира. Классический пример тот же самый Толкиен со своими кольцами: придуман внутренне непротиворечивый мир с иерархией персонажей с разными расами, есть общая сюжетная линия, есть основная идея и все такое.

Так вот мессидж то в чем? Толкать гуманитария в быдлокодеры это неправильно. Надо метить в архитекторы или по меньшей мере в тим лидеры. Пусть подучит UML, методы ведения прожектов и проч. Гуманитарию это будет сподручнее чем биться с идиотскими атрибутами разметок или с дебрями каскадных стилей.

Ну конечно, технологии знать надо - но начинать с HTML это в общем то маразм. Пусть сразу берет в руки кайло типа Java/C#/C/C++ и вперед.

Comment: > в несчастного веб кодера

> Толкать гуманитария в быдлокодеры

Насколько я понимаю, в вашем представлении, веб дев(уточню - который пишет не на Java/C#/C/C++/etc), в своем большинстве, это толком ничего не умеющее УГ. Мой скромный опыт показывает, что среди C#/C++/C/Java/etc разработчиков гавнокода и плохих практик не меньше, а степень упоротости писавшего, нередко, стремиться к небесам и приводит к мыслям об убийстве куда чаще

> начинать с HTML это в общем то маразм

Эм, ИМХО, любого рода разработчик вообще не знающий HTML (даже если это не веб дев), это, как-бы, печально, не?

Comment: Как бы объяснить то... HTML отношение к программированию имеет ровно столько же сколько имеет отношение знание английского к программированию. Знать надо, но считать знание HTML входным билетом к программированию - как то неэтично даже. Вебдев это все таки более гордо, нежели HTML верстальщик, не?

Comment: поставил + за мнение )

> гуманитария в несчастного веб кодера

почему же сразу в несчастного?

> В программировании все не так.

Быдло кодеры рассуждают четко: если, то, иначе. Но суть программиста в том, что он из этих правильных конструкций, создает свой мир (как вы уже сказали), причем мир зачастую не подчиняется четким последовательностям. Программист должен иметь хорошее воображение, смотреть на всю задачу издали.

> Так вот мессидж то в чем? Толкать гуманитария в быдлокодеры это неправильно.

- Мне нужен стул, как его сделать?
- Делай сразу диван, на нем можно спать.

Comment: @Barmaley, а причем здесь верстальщик? Вы же пишите о тим-лидах, архитекторах и т.п., архитектор который не знает HTML? четко...

Comment: > Знать надо, но считать знание HTML входным билетом к программированию - как то неэтично даже.
а еще зачем человеку ползать, он же может сразу бегать научиться?, ведь ползание относится к бегу так же как и HTML к веб разработчику?

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо, Вы помогаете мне понемногу понимать ООП

       придумать сюжет (идея программы), 

В ООП сюжет ещё круче (теологический). Мир был пуст, и пришёл программер и населил мир объектами, которые сами живут, и с другими объектами общаются. И населил ими мир, и нажал кнопку Start, и всё завертелось... А в результате междусобойчика объектов получается нужный программисту результат.

Так что гуманитарию не надо ломать мозги. Мозги надо ломать технарям...

Comment: html и другие страшные слова - это всего лишь инструменты, позволяющие добиться определенных целей. знание html не сделает гуманитария программистом, пусть даже и веб. из всего списка, имхо, основное - это 13 пункт из ответа @IVsevolod. все остальное гуглится по мере продвижения в обучении. пытливость ума - первичный "половой" признак программиста.  
ЗЫ тимлидер, рассказывающий команде про персонажи и сюжет - это тот еще цирк будет ))

Comment: @alexlz, вопрос тут в том, а этот мир будет крутиться? Или быстренько подвиснет...

А по делу, так ТС надо просто для начала прочесть какую-нибудь книжку по программированию  и понять интересны ли ему подобные алгоритмические головоломки.

Если захватывают, то можно уже думать в какой области дальше изучать.

Comment: @avp: это зависит от умелости Демиурга! Наш-то мир вон как глючит :-D Явно отладочный билд.

Comment: @avp И с каких книг начинать гуманитарию? С R. Gabriel'а (www.dreamsongs.com)?

А насчёт ООП -- раньше я его считал очень хорошим инструментом для симуляционного моделирования (вспомните Simula67). Оказалось, что и тут есть инструменты получше...

Comment: @alexlz,  с чего начать именно гуманитарию, не знаю.

Мне, например, классе в 9-м средней школы случайно попалась толстая книга про системное программирование для IBM 360 (на русском, конечно). 

Как устроены ассемблер, линкер, загрузчик и т.п. Помню, здорово меня тогда эти "головоломки" захватили.

Про ЭВМ и программирование  я в то время почти ничего и не знал.

Comment: Толстая книга про системное программирование... Я помню из толстых "Программирование на IBM/360" Кларенс Джермейн. Но содержание уже не помнится. С той техникой я завязал давно.

Comment: @alexlz, вспомнил ([и даже нашел](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7263678/), чего только сейчас в сети нет, просто поразительно).

Answer (score 6):

Сначала определитесь, что Вам ближе: Веб, прикладное, системное, мобильное.. Если без разницы, то можете и не начинать, это не для Вас. На данный момент самыми востребованными считаются программисты java и c#. Я как java программист, могу посоветовать начать с Deitel, How to program Java. В русском варианте ее нет, но там объясняется все с самого нуля. Помимо этого смотрите видеолекции (на Youtube их полно) и закрепляйте знания на практике, придумывайте условия сами и решайте. Когда будете уверенно выполнять такие задачки, зайдите на какой-нибудь сайт фрилансеров и посмотрите что к чему, подтягивайте знания и пишите программы уже там. Дальше само пойдет. Удачи.

Comment: > самыми востребованными считаются программисты java и c#.
Java понятно, это да. Но сколько проектов на C# вы знаете?, а сколько сайтов ежедневно пишется на том же PHP, Perl?

Answer (score 4):

Ух какая дискуссия! А мне вопрос весьма по нраву! Только вот о сроках большинство молчит. 2-3 года - понятие весьма относительное, потому как не ясно в каких условиях эти 2-3 года заниматься, а учить надо много и усердно. Вам бы действительно определиться с курсом. Но от себя считаю нужным добавить, что только денежная мотивация в вопросах программирования - это намного хуже, чем если бы к этому был прибавлен интерес самой сути.

Я бы вам посоветовал призвать тот факт, что ничего серьёзного качественно не освоить если заниматься этим после основной работы.

Answer (score 3):

Странный вопрос - почему его не задают себе сотни миллионов людей?
Логичнее, задать поставить вопрос - не КАК, а ЗАЧЕМ?
Вот как мне стать космонавтом, дворником или шахтёром? ;)
Да взять и пойти в шахту.
Как стать экономистом - взять и пойти поступить в ВУЗ на экономФак.
От такой постановки вопросов, я могу судить об одном, - У Вас странное мышление, а значит и логика...
В программировании, как в основном и в других науках, специальностях без ХОРОШЕЙ логики и ПРАВИЛЬНОГО мышления будет очень тяжело и учиться, и тем более качественно трудиться.

```
Какая структура знаний должна быть?
```

Логичная: Теория+ практика

```
Что мне нужно знать? Какие языки учить и в какой последовательности?
```

Знать - чем больше и глубже, тем лучше.
Языки, те которые нужны по направлению. Веб - значит вэб. Прикладное - значит прикладные.
Низкоуровневые - значит таковые.
Последовательность, от простых до серьезных
Я начинал с DOS (bat-файлов), потом HTML+CSS, немного попробовал JavaScript, потом было Delphi+DB+MS Access, потом PHP+mySQL.
Всё ведь логично.

---

P.S. Не стоит гуманитарию идти в технические науки.
Ни чего хорошего из этого не выйдет.

Comment: I_CaR
Во-первых, спасибо за ответ и личные примеры.

Однако, касательно вашего первого замечания, я с вами не соглашусь.

ЗАЧЕМ - я четко очертил в вопросе:
-"...хочу работать по призванию"
-"...превратить свое увлечение в дополнительный источник дохода"

Поэтому, я задал вопрос сперва себе, а потом и всем: 
КАК мне это сделать?
-Какая структура знаний должна быть?
-На чем основывать свое обучение?
-На чем сконцентрироваться в порядке очередности?

Поэтому, я считаю что мыслю логично и последовательно.

Comment: Delphi уважаю, я с него начинал. И на мой взгляд Pascal-е подобный синтаксис наиболее удобный для старта в программировании )

Comment: @I_CaR, у меня мышление и логика еще более странные и ничего, мне меньше чем 2-3 года понадобилось.

Comment: @AlexWindHope у программистов у всех странное мышление )

Answer (score 3):

1й ответ хорош. Попробую внести немного конкретики по части языков.
Попробуйте начать с Pyton, он простой и приятный, к тому же вполне злободневен. Потом C# и/или Java. Это 2 очень похожих языка, достаточно большая доля вакансий девелоперов требует знания 1ого из них - по моему, это показатель.

По вышеперечисленным языкам есть множество литературы на любой вкус.

- посмотрите HTML для понимания того что это такое.
- SQL

После всего вышеперечисленного можно начать писать собственные приложения под мобильные платформы (Androdid, Windows mobile, Firefox os - возможно тоже будет популярна через пару лет).

Если для вас это будет хобби, то написание и продажа мобильных приложений, как мне кажется, будет лучшим методом монетизации.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вы пытаетесь зарабатывать программированием?  Я не очень рад тому, что мне пришлось моё хобби превратить в профессию.  Иногда приходится выполнять работу на скорую руку и кое-как, что очень неприятно с позиции моего перфекционизма.  Я люблю писать программы вдумчиво, не спеша и с удовольствием - только тогда получается то, чем потом гордишься.  Представьте, что вы художник, а заказчик хочет получить от вас такую размазню, что вам самому её писать противно.  Такие моменты трудно пережить, не потеряв часть вдохновения, так важного в искусстве.  Лучше быть маркетологом с хорошим окладом, а своим хобби (рисование, программирование и т.п.) заниматься в остальное время.

По вопросу "где учиться".  Я учился не на программиста, но курсе на 3-м уже точно знал, что буду им.  Да и работодателю пофиг, где программисты учились.   Им важен опыт, а не диплом.  Знания устаревают очень быстро, и ни один ВУЗ не поспевает готовить актуальных программистов.  Тут вы ничего не потеряли - вам, как и всем остальным, придётся обучаться на ходу.

Comment: Ответ не совсем по делу. ТС не собирается учиться в вузе. Он как раз хочет заняться самообразованием и спрашивает, с чего начать.

Comment: Егор, я на данном этапе не ставлю цель заработка на программировании. 
Я хочу реализовать себя, и сделать это на качественном уровне. Для этого нужна определенная система или структура как строить свое обучении и в каком направлении.
Финансовая сторона вопроса возникнет при определенном опыте и возможности конкурировать, а процесс работы с заказчиком придаток от которого не деться =)

Comment: Не хочу создавать новый ответ, но темпы разработки очень зависят от места работы. Где-то надо, чтобы всё работало "вчера", а в других местах можно несколько вариантов реализовать и не опоздать со сроками.

По поводу того, что превращение хобби в профессию это плохо.. Тоже не согласен. Намного приятнее заниматься тем, что тебе нравится, чем чем-то другим.

:) На правах пищи для размышлений.

Comment: @xEdelweiss - насчёт "можно несколько вариантов реализовать и не опоздать со сроками" - это фантастика.  Кто вам за вашу нерасторопность будет з/пл платить?  Работа программистом - это работа на капиталиста, у которого интересы понятно какие.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff, что касается нерасторопности и фантастики - это ваши домыслы. "Интересы понятно какие" - ваша точка зрения. Работа не всегда предполагает сделать что-то только бы заработало, есть заказчики, которые хотят качественного результата. А качественно не всегда можно сделать просто постучав ко клавиатуре.

Comment: @xEdelweiss - сколько живу, ни разу таких идеальных и терпеливых заказчиков не видел.  ))))   Там, где платят не копейки, всегда не позволяют расслабляться и выдавать меньше, чем мог бы (по мнению начальника).  Если у вас есть реальные контрпримеры - в студию!

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff, нет. На этом я закончу этот бессмысленный спор.

Comment: @xEdelweiss - Неудивительно, что тебе нечем подвердить истинность своего опрометчивого заявления.  У тебя нет реального опыта работы (судя по твоему возрасту в профиле), и жизнь ещё не поводила тебя фейсом об тейбл, в голове у тебя ещё радужные мечты вместо осознания не очень красивой реальности.  Ты согласишься со мной, но чуть позже ;-)

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff мечтатель :D Что такое писать код "вдумчиво"? Разве вы генерируете проект "на лету"?

Что такое "получать удовольствие"? ~70% процентов вашего времени занимает то, что вы делали раньше. Какое же это удовольствие?

На скорую руку можно вполне нормальный проект сделать: готовое решение + модули, подправить чуток - заказчик доволен, деньги появились, время осталось.

Comment: По поводу хобби: это ж вообще круто, на работе можно заниматься своими проектами и никто тебе и слова не скажет, ведь ты программируешь) А детально изучать, что ты там делаешь либо никто не сумеет в силу своих знаний, либо просто лень.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я бы хотел вспомнить мысль из книги "Верёвка достаточной длины, чтобы выстрелить себе в ногу": лучшие программисты получаются из гуманитариев, потому что гуманитарии лучше, чем технари, умеют выражать свои мысли.

Если Вы из Питера, можете поучиться у меня (правда, я специализируюсь на прикладном программировании, но базовые вещи всё равно не повредят).